Best Approach to Smooth ETA Transitions in Delivery Prediction Models
I'm working on displaying the ETA (Estimated Time of Arrival) for an item delivery using a predictive model that evolves over time. The issue I'm facing involves smoothing the transition between initial and subsequent ETA predictions.
Problem Description
Initial Prediction Accuracy: The model initially provides a very inaccurate ETA (the star in the figure attached represents this initial prediction). As time progresses and more information becomes available, the ETA predictions become more accurate. This can result in a large gap (20-30 minutes) between the first and second predictions.
Stable Predictions: After the second prediction, the ETA often remains constant for a period before eventually updating. For instance, in the provided figure, the ETA remains at 10 minutes from 17:31 to 17:37 before starting to decrease slightly.
Current Approach
I am smoothing the ETA values to handle the transition from the initial inaccurate prediction to the more accurate subsequent prediction, using a simple exponentially weighted moving average.
Questions:
Handling Large Gaps: What are effective techniques for smoothing or mitigating the 20-minute gap between the initial and second ETA predictions? (Which is my main concern)
Addressing Stable ETA Values: How should one approach the issue of the ETA not changing for several minutes? Is there a user experience-based reason to adjust this behavior, or is it acceptable as is?
Additional Context:
I’m unsure whether simply applying a smoothing function to the ETA values is the best solution, or if there are more sophisticated methods to handle these two issues effectively. Any insights or suggestions for improving the display of ETA predictions would be greatly appreciated
